# An infinite while loop in python with pandas calculating the standard deviation

Tags: python, pandas, csv, infinite-loop, standard-deviation

### We're trying to delete outliers, but got an infinite loop instead

For a school project we (me and a friend) decided it'd be a good idea to create a tool based on data science. For this we started cleaning a database (I  won't import it here because it is too big ([xlsx file](https://static.rijdendetreinen.nl/data/disruptions/2019/disruptions-2011-2019.xlsx), [csv file](https://static.rijdendetreinen.nl/data/disruptions/2019/disruptions-2011-2019.csv))). We're now trying to delete outliers using the 'standard deviation*3 + mean' rule for the column 'duration_minutes'.

Here is the code we used to calculate the standard-deviation and the mean:

```
def calculateSD(database, column):
    column = database[[column]]
    SD = column.std(axis=None, skipna=None, level=None, ddof=1, numeric_only=None)
    return SD

def calculateMean(database, column):
    column = database[[column]]
    mean = column.mean()
    return mean
```

We thought to do the following:

```
#Now we have to remove the outliers using the code from the SD.py and SDfunction.py files
minutes = trainsData['duration_minutes'].tolist() #takes the column duration_minutes and puts it in a list
SD = int(calculateSD(trainsData, 'duration_minutes')) #calculates the SD of the column
mean = int(calculateMean(trainsData, 'duration_minutes'))
SDhigh = mean+3*SD
```

The code above calculates the beginning values. Then we started a while-loop to delete outliers. After the outliers are deleted, we re-calculate the standard-deviation, the mean, and the SDhigh again. This is the while-loop:

```
while np.any(i >= SDhigh for i in minutes): #used to be >=, it doesnt matter for the outcome
    trainsData = trainsData[trainsData['duration_minutes'] < SDhigh] #used to be >=, this caused an infinite loop so I changed it to <=. Then to <
    minutes = trainsData['duration_minutes'].tolist()
    SD = int(calculateSD(trainsData, 'duration_minutes')) #calculates the SD of the column
    mean = int(calculateMean(trainsData, 'duration_minutes'))
    SDhigh = mean+3*SD
    print(SDhigh) #to see how the values changed and to confirm it is an infinite loop
```

the output is along the lines of the following:

```
611
652
428
354
322
308
300
296
296
296
296
```

it continues to print 296, and after hours of trying to solve it we came to the conclusion that we're not as smart as we wished.

---

TL;DR: We're trying to remove all values higher than standard-deviation*3+mean, until none are left (we re-calculate this every time to check if there still are outliers left). However, we get an infinite loop.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: One potential issue could be that you are casting the mean and std to int which will change the values. Try using float instead.

Comment: Try checking what the maximum value is, before and after the deletion (and label your outputs so you know what's what).

Comment: Thanks! although changing the type back to a float gave me some errors, appearently the whole while loop wasn't needed - the rule we were trying to use only needed to be applied once. We really appreciate your quick awnsers, so thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making things more difficult than they have to be. Calculating the standard deviation to remove outliers and then recalculating it etc is overly complicated (and statistically un-sound). You are better off by using percentile instead of standard deviation

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create data
nums = np.random.normal(50, 8, 200)
df = pd.DataFrame(nums, columns=['duration'])

# set threshold based on percentiles
threshold = df['duration'].quantile(.95) * 2

# now only keep rows that are below the threshold
df = df[df['duration']<threshold]
```